# How would I layout my JTable to separate SQL data?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jtable

I'm looking to layout my JTable to show each exercise separately. Currently it is storing everything in one table. The JTable in the image is how it is currently showing. I think I may need to make separate JTables for each but I'm not sure. I'm wanting to make it looks similar to the other image provided so when I click a JButton, it will generate the table with a JLabel above it stating the name of the exercise and the Body Area for each of the exercises. Unsure if there is a better way without all the tables.

[image: Current JTable]

[image: Similar layout I want]

I've tried adding everything to seperate JTables and adding them to the JScroll Pane but unable to get the second table to show.

Comment: What do you want your GUI to look like?  Do you want to show one exercise at a time, like your second image, or several exercises on one `JPanel`?  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not convinced, based on the desired output, that a `JTable` would be the best solution

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I would like the layout similar to the second image, but have everything on a single jpanel so I can scroll to view all sets etc for the different exercises

Comment: @MadProgrammer would you be able to suggest an alternative way to lay this out?

Comment: A series of specialised components each focusing on a single goal

Comment: Your image has three vertical dots at the end of each line.  What do these vertical dots signify?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I’m not worrying about all the small details in the second image, I just mean the layout. For example having something similar to a JLabel at the top stating the exercise name, then the sets etc below it in a table or something similar, then repeat for the next exercise, having it below the first on the same panel so all exercises of the workout can be seen

Answer (score 0):

## Introduction

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I went ahead and created the following GUI.  I didn't worry about making it pretty.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

[image: Page 1]

Here's the same GUI scrolled down a page.

[image: Page 2]

## Explanation

The hardest part of coding this was creating the application model.  Most of the code is devoted to creating the application model.  Once I had the application model done, coding the GUI was straightforward.  Using the model-view-controller (MVC) pattern makes creating a GUI so much easier.

### Model

The application model consists of three classes.  `ExerciseModel` is the main plain Java getter/setter model class.  It holds a `java.util.List` of `Exercise` instances and a `List` of `ExerciseType` instances.

`Exercise` is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds the results of one set of one exercise.  I based this class on your original table image.

`ExerciseType` is a plain Java getter/setter class that holds a type of exercise.

### View

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I created a `JTablePanel` class to create the `JTable` `JPanel`.  I made it a class because I was going to need as many instances of the class as there were exercise types.

The rest of the view is a straightforward creation of the `JFrame` and `JPanels`.

There are no controller classes in this example.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class ExerciseGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ExerciseGUI());
    }
    
    private final ExerciseModel model;
    
    public ExerciseGUI() {
        this.model = new ExerciseModel();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Exercise GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    private JScrollPane createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 5, 5));
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
        
        Dimension tablePanelDimension = new Dimension(0, 0);
        List<ExerciseType> exerciseTypes = model.getExerciseTypes();
        for (ExerciseType exerciseType : exerciseTypes) {
            JPanel tablePanel = new JTablePanel(model, exerciseType).getPanel();
            tablePanelDimension = tablePanel.getPreferredSize();
            panel.add(tablePanel);
        }
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(tablePanelDimension.width + 50, 
                tablePanelDimension.height));
        
        return scrollPane;
    }
    
    public class JTablePanel {
        
        private final ExerciseModel model;
        
        private final ExerciseType exerciseType;
        
        private final JPanel panel;
        
        public JTablePanel(ExerciseModel model, ExerciseType exerciseType) {
            this.model = model;
            this.exerciseType = exerciseType;
            this.panel = createJTablePanel();
        }

        private JPanel createJTablePanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 5));
            
            JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 30, 5));
            
            JLabel exerciseLabel = new JLabel(exerciseType.getExercise());
            titlePanel.add(exerciseLabel);
            
            JLabel bodyAreaLabel = new JLabel(exerciseType.getBodyArea());
            titlePanel.add(bodyAreaLabel);
            
            panel.add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            
            JTable table = new JTable(createTableModel());
            
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            return panel;
        }
        
        private DefaultTableModel createTableModel() {
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
            tableModel.addColumn("Set");
            tableModel.addColumn("Weight");
            tableModel.addColumn("Reps");
            
            for (Exercise exercise : model.getExercises()) {
                if (exercise.getExercise().equals(exerciseType.getExercise())) {
                    Object[] rowData = new Object[3];
                    rowData[0] = exercise.getSet();
                    rowData[1] = exercise.getWeight();
                    rowData[2] = exercise.getReps();
                    tableModel.addRow(rowData);
                }
            }
            
            return tableModel;
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ExerciseModel {
        
        private final List<Exercise> exercises;
        
        private final List<ExerciseType> exerciseTypes;
        
        public ExerciseModel() {
            this.exercises = createExercise();
            this.exerciseTypes = createExerciseTypes(exercises);
        }
        
        private List<Exercise> createExercise() {
            List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Chest Press", "Chest", 1, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Chest Press", "Chest", 2, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Chest Press", "Chest", 3, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Chest Press", "Chest", 4, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Chest Press", "Chest", 5, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Deadlift", "Back", 1, 10, 70));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Deadlift", "Back", 2, 10, 70));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Deadlift", "Back", 3, 10, 70));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Deadlift", "Back", 4, 10, 70));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Deadlift", "Back", 5, 10, 70));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Kickbacks", "Tricept", 1, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Kickbacks", "Tricept", 2, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Kickbacks", "Tricept", 3, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Kickbacks", "Tricept", 4, 10, 12));
            exercises.add(new Exercise("Kickbacks", "Tricept", 5, 10, 12));
            
            return exercises;
        }
        
        private List<ExerciseType> createExerciseTypes(
                List<Exercise> exercises) {
            List<ExerciseType> exerciseTypes = new ArrayList<>();
            String previousExercise = "", previousBodyArea;
            for (Exercise exercise : exercises) {
                if (!previousExercise.equals(exercise.getExercise())) {
                    previousExercise = exercise.getExercise();
                    previousBodyArea = exercise.getBodyArea();
                    exerciseTypes.add(new ExerciseType(previousExercise,
                            previousBodyArea));
                }
            }
            
            return exerciseTypes;
        }

        public List<Exercise> getExercises() {
            return exercises;
        }

        public List<ExerciseType> getExerciseTypes() {
            return exerciseTypes;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class Exercise {
        
        private final int set, weight, reps;
        
        private final String exercise, bodyArea;

        public Exercise(String exercise, String bodyArea, int set, int reps,
                int weight) {
            this.exercise = exercise;
            this.bodyArea = bodyArea;
            this.set = set;
            this.reps = reps;
            this.weight = weight;
        }

        public int getSet() {
            return set;
        }

        public int getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public int getReps() {
            return reps;
        }

        public String getExercise() {
            return exercise;
        }

        public String getBodyArea() {
            return bodyArea;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class ExerciseType {
        
        private final String exercise, bodyArea;

        public ExerciseType(String exercise, String bodyArea) {
            this.exercise = exercise;
            this.bodyArea = bodyArea;
        }

        public String getExercise() {
            return exercise;
        }

        public String getBodyArea() {
            return bodyArea;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much for the help! I just need to try to break this down and understand each part, then integrate it with my sql database